# HTMLWebpackPlugin from npm using custom template with .headTags is empty

Tags: javascript, webpack, html-webpack-plugin

I want to set the options to `inject: false` and use `<%= htmlWebpackPlugin.tags.headTags %>` to put the generated tags in a place of my choosing in the template I am using as a file.

I have multiple entry points in webpack and each entry point needs to be output as its own `<entryName>Partial.html` to actually navigate to in the browser.

I thought `<%= htmlWebpackPlugin.tags.headTags %>` would work to included the depended files imported for the relevant entry and it would sub it out in my template but it is empty. The following, however, ***DOES WORK***:

`<% for (var chunk in htmlWebpackPlugin.files.js) { %><script src="<%= htmlWebpackPlugin.files.js[chunk]%>"></script><% } %>`

I dont see much documentation on `htmlWebpackPlugin.files.` so I'm scared I might miss out on some other files if I dont use something more generic like the proposed `.headTags` that isnt working for me. i.e. like css files or anything else that might be there

Comment: I had an `undefined` error on `htmlWebpackPlugin.tags` and I found your question... for reference, .tags is supported starting from html-webpack-plugin 4.0 and vue-cli ~4.5.0 depends on ~3.2.0, see https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin/issues/1284

Comment: so that 4.0 beta has it, but the 4.5.1 latest version for `https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-webpack-plugin/v/4.5.1` doesnt have it?? Oh these documents..why even reference it. I cant figure it out

Comment: No, sorry, confusing version numbers: vue-cli@next is 4.5.0 and uses html-webpack-plugin ~3.2.0. Newer html-webpack-plugin versions (including 4.5.1...) should have it (and you do have it, even if it's empty: in my case instead of being empty I was getting an error. If you use html-webpack-plugin 4.5.1 it should be there.